# When constructing a Swift UnsafeMutablePointer manually, is destroy/dealloc obligatory after alloc?

Tags: swift, memory-management

Let's say that in Swift I construct a C array manually and pass it, like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    var arr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>.alloc(4)
    arr[0] = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
    arr[1] = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
    arr[2] = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
    arr[3] = CGPoint(x:0,y:100)
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(c, arr, 4)
}
```

(I know I don't *have* to do that, but just bear with me.) If I don't call `destroy` and/or `dealloc` on this UnsafeMutablePointer, am I leaking the memory for four CGPoints?

Comment: Can't you use XCode to check for memory leaks?

Comment: You'll leak memory if you don't call `arr.dealloc(4)`. This seems to be a good overview (perhaps a duplicate?) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670643/confusion-regarding-terminology-concerning-unsafemutablepointers-destroy

Comment: @doctordoder Did you try it? There are no CGPoint objects here - it's just a block of memory somewhere, so I can't readily pick it out among all the blocks of memory.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks and I'll rewrite to include `dealloc` in the question; I didn't mean to limit what my obligations might be. However, that question is where I _started_ (note my comment/question after the answer); it isn't  definitely telling me what I'd like to know.

Comment: @matt: I just noticed that you had already seen the other answer ...

Comment: Also @MartinR The headers say that precondition for `dealloc` is that the memory is not initialized. But the memory _is_ initialized, is it not? That is what my assignment of values into it has done...

Comment: This alloc/initialize/destroy/dealloc stuff is just extremely poor documented. Perhaps your posting in the developer forum gives some results. As I understand it, destroy() calls the deinit method of the objects, which is a no-op for CGPoint, so that you can safely omit that. dealloc() is the counterpart of alloc() (as in malloc/free), so without that you'll leak memory.

Comment: ... This is also confirmed by using the Leaks Instruments tool, with your code repeatedly called in a timer function.

Comment: "This alloc/initialize/destroy/dealloc stuff is just extremely poor documented.” Really? The documentation in the standard lib comments (which the Swift dev team has explicitly stated is the official place for the documentation, though it would be nice to have it on a web page too) seems pretty good to me.

Comment: @MartinR Your timer test is a nice idea. The thing is, however, if I add `destroy` and `dealloc`, I still see a steady rise in memory use (in fact it looks worse).

Answer (score 15):

The documentation for `UnsafeMutablePointer` is pretty clear:

```
///                      This type provides no automated
/// memory management, and therefore the user must take care to allocate
/// and free memory appropriately.
```

So if you allocate but don’t deallocate, you will leak memory.  There’s no auto-deallocation on destruction of the pointer object.

Re whether you should destroy before deallocating, it’s also pretty clear:

```
/// The pointer can be in one of the following states:
///
/// - memory is not allocated (for example, pointer is null, or memory has
/// been deallocated previously);
///
/// - memory is allocated, but value has not been initialized;
///
/// - memory is allocated and value is initialized.
```

But bear in mind you can transition back and forth between these states.  So after allocating then initializing then de-initialzing (aka destroying) the objects, the memory is no longer in the “initialized” state, so you can either re-initialize or deallocate it.  You can also allocate, then deallocate, without ever initializing.

And when calling `dealloc`:

```
/// Deallocate `num` objects.
...
/// Precondition: the memory is not initialized.
///
/// Postcondition: the memory has been deallocated.
```

Therefore you *must* call destroy on any initialized objects before calling `dealloc`.  You are probably right in that since something like `CGPoint` is totally inert (just a struct of two floating point nums) it *probably* doesn’t do any harm not to call `destroy` before you call `dealloc` but you can’t be certain without knowing the implementation (of both the pointer struct and the compiler probably, since the standard lib is a quasi-part of the language there could be some baked-in optimizations), and generally, it’s just not a good habit to get into.  Sooner or later you’ll forget to destroy a `String`, and then you’ll be sorry.

(none of this accounts for the `move` operations btw which combine initializing new memory with destroying old memory)

If you were hoping for some kind of automated self-cleanup of memory by `UnsafePointer`, I don’t think this would be possible as a) it’s a struct, so can’t implement a `deinit` to auto-deallocate when going out of scope, and b) it doesn’t track it’s own size – you have to track how much you allocate, and supply that back explicitly in the call to `deallocate`.

There is something in the standard library that does auto-deallocate memory without you having to do it yourself – `HeapBufferStorage`, the one and only class in the standard library.  Presumably it’s a class specifically to benefit from an implementation of `deinit`.  There’s also `HeapBuffer` to manage it with, and this has a handy `isUniquelyReferenced()` function that allows you to tell if it’s been copied (even though it’s a struct) and so would allow you to implement copy-on-write capability similar to arrays and strings.

Comment: When using Martin R's idea of a repeating timer to cause redraw of my view I see a steady rise in memory usage regardless of whether I call `destroy` and `dealloc` or not. Thus I'm not convinced that this makes a difference.

Comment: Bear in mind, just because you give memory back to the runtime with dealloc doesn’t mean the runtime will give it straight back to the OS...

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 2 UnsafeMutablePointer can be made a bit less frustrating by pairing alloc/dealloc with the new `defer` keyword:

```
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
defer { ptr.dealloc(1) }
```

Comment: What if I declare a var in class instead of within the fun ? Should I implement `deinit` function and call `destroy ` and then `dealloc` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for others like me who found this question/answer thread by searching CGContextStrokeLineSegments. If your purpose is to call this function in Swift, you don't have to construct a C array pointer even though the function's second parameter is an UnsafeMutablePointer. You can directly pass a Swift array into it, even a non-mutable one, instead of a C pointer with its allocation and deallocation. For example:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
   if let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
   {
       let arr = [CGPoint(x:0,y:0), CGPoint(x:50,y:50), CGPoint(x:50,y:50), CGPoint(x:0,y:100)]
       CGContextStrokeLineSegments(c, arr, 4)
   }
}
```

Comment: Question stipulates: "I know I don't have to do that, but just bear with me" so you're off topic