# In Swift; what is the proper way to free memory allocated using UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate

Tags: swift, memory-management, signal-processing

First, I am aware I can use Swift Array's but I don't own the memory then. The array does. I wan't to allocate my own arrays.  Writing a class for this I need a deinit to free my allocated memory when the object is done. So I have writen the following test code.  I want to know the proper way to free this memory.  I notice the buffer is a true object and has a deinitialize and a dealloc.  I also notice I can just free it.  Concerned with the free I might be freeing the object and leaving the memory as an orphan.  Anyway thought I would see what others think.

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

let buffer:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: 100)
var s = Float(1.0)
var i = Float(1.0)
vDSP_vramp(&s, &i, buffer, 1, 100)
print("after positive ramp stride one")
for i in 0..<10{
    print(buffer[i])
}
s = -1.0; i = -1.0
vDSP_vramp(&s, &i, buffer, 2, 50)
print("after negative ramp stride two")
print("result of print with stride one")
for i in 0..<10{
    print(buffer[i])
}
print("print result with stride 2")
for i in 0..<10{
    print(buffer[2 * i])
}
print()
buffer.deinitialize()
print("after deinitialize")
print(buffer[1])
free(buffer)
print("after free")
print(buffer[1])
```

Output looks like

```
after positive ramp stride one
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
after negative ramp stride two
result of print with stride one
-1.0
2.0
-2.0
4.0
-3.0
6.0
-4.0
8.0
-5.0
10.0
print result with stride 2
-1.0
-2.0
-3.0
-4.0
-5.0
-6.0
-7.0
-8.0
-9.0
-10.0

after deinitialize
2.0
after free
0.0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: The counterpart to `...allocate(capacity: 100)`  is `buffer.deallocate(capacity: 100)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175870/how-to-handle-unsafemutablepointer-correctly

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768290/when-constructing-a-swift-unsafemutablepointer-manually-is-destroy-dealloc-obli.